# Weird problem with UIBarButtonItem in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

First of all, sorry: I'm pretty sure there's something incredibly stupid I'm doing here, and that I should absolutely go to sleep right now.

The problem is that I added an `UIBarButtonItem` to a nib and wired it to the right outlet, but after my view has been loaded, the ivar I connected is still `nil`. Is this supposed to work at all, or it only works when you drag the bar button inside a navigation bar in Interface Builder?

Comment: By the way, I considered the idea of creating the button in code, but I really want to know why this isn't working with IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `UIBarButtonItem` was inside an `UIViewController` instantiated by a `UITabBarController`, but I had forgotten to set the "Nib Name" field in the view controller's Attributes.